# Angular detect If checkbox is checked from the .ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 4 and I have a checkbox on my component on the component's html template file:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="canBeEditable($event)">
```

On my component's .ts file I have this which set's the value to true.

```
toggleEditable() {
    this.contentEditable = true;
}
```

My problem is that I only want the value changed IF the checkbox IS checked.

So it would look something like:

```
toggleEditable() {
    if (checkbox is checked) {
      this.contentEditable = true;
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox element is checked in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043265/check-if-checkbox-element-is-checked-in-typescript)

Comment: That doesn't work on my app. HTMLInputElement is not a type it knows

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to check `event.target.checked` to solve this issue. This is how you can achieve that:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleEditable($event)">
```

In your component's .ts:

```
toggleEditable(event) {
     if ( event.target.checked ) {
         this.contentEditable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for radio buttons as well? `event.target.checked` always results as true after the radio button has been clicked once.

Comment: What would be type of 'event' in this case? if i use typescript.

Comment: @nikhil do you have an answer for this?

Comment: Just do `event.checked` in typescript (you can print the variable `event` to see what field it contains, this would have easily give you the answer :) )

Comment: umm, it's a toggle.  Why not just: html - `<input ... (change)="toggleEditable()">`, ts - `toggleEditable() { this.editable = !this.editable; }`